# Get 1 input field value to 2 different controllers by using 2 buttons

Tags: javascript, forms, codeigniter, model-view-controller, controller

I have a `<form>` which currently sends the input field data to 1 function in the controller. Which looks like this.

```
<?php echo form_open('moneyexchange/invest_first_page');  ?>
  <input  type="text" placeholder="Amount in &euro;"  name="writtenamount"/>
    <button class="btn btn-lg" type="submit" >Invest</button> 
    <button class="btn btn-lg" type="submit" >Borrow</button>
<?php echo form_close();?>
```

The problem is I need Invest button to go to invest_first_page function inside money exchange controller, and the Borrow button to go to a different function inside the same controller called borrow_first_page. I need to use one input field and it is a must, so cannot use two input fields and then after that they go to the function they are redirected to two different pages,so is there any way to get this form to post the input value to two different controller when clicked on different buttons.

Just for extra information I am posting both the function in controller which the buttons direct too.

```
    public function invest_first_page(){
$this->load->helper('form');
         $this->load->library('form_validation');
        $this->load->view('header');
        $userProvidedAmount = $this->input->post("writtenamount");
        $data =  array(
        'userProvidedAmount' => $userProvidedAmount
         );
        $this->load->view("invest_firstpage", $data);
        $this->load->view('footer');
                }

 public function borrow_first_page(){
        }
```

Can I use JavaScript be used to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Paul Rolas code is perfect but there is 2 things you need to consider, since your not using value in your place holder so your data should be like this

```
data: { writtenamount: $("#amount").data('value')},
```

And most probably its better to use method instead of type

```
method: 'POST',
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Example Below

```
    <html>
<head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $( document ).ready(function() {
            $('#yourbuttonid').click(function() { 
                $.ajax({
                     url: 'moneyexchange/invest_first_page',
                     type: 'POST',
                     data: { writtenamount: $("#amount").val()},
                     success: function (result) {
                       // do stuff
                     }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <?php echo form_open('moneyexchange/invest_first_page');  ?>
        <input  type="text" placeholder="Amount in &euro;"  name="writtenamount"/>
        <button id="yourbuttonid" class="btn btn-lg" type="submit" >Invest</button> 
        <button class="btn btn-lg" type="submit" >Borrow</button>
    <?php echo form_close();?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hey I tried your code, did not work, 
I even added the button id like this
<button class="btn btn-lg" type="submit" id="yourbuttonid" >Invest</button>

Comment: How do I fix the form, do I keep the form_open there? since its redirecting to one specific controller

Comment: In your controller are you seeing the value writtenamount set? meaning is it visible when you are debugging?

Comment: I put my controller function just incase so you see it, and when I debug it doesnt even reach the controller

Comment: inside of your click function write alert("clicked"); a message box should show up on the screen does that work?

Comment: And I cannot use the form_open money exchange / invest first page, since I am going to redirect the value to two different controllers hence I Am using ajax

Answer (score 0):

you could use the OnSubmit event of the form to do that. ([look here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onsubmit.asp))
You could simply catch the event and route to the needed controller.

Comment: to route it to those controller

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things you can do.

**1) Give your buttons a name attribute**

You're saying that you are restricted to only one input field, but you forget that the button you click can also be used to pass data. Then in your php script you'll check which button was clicked and then do whatever functionality you need based on that.

**2) Use Ajax to send your postdata**

You could use javascript (or preferably jQuery) to handle the post request for you. You give both buttons a different id-tag, so `<button id="button1">` and `<button id="button2">`. With this information you can then use javascript to find which button was clicked, and make an ajax request to the right php function.

Comment: Can you show me how to write the code so I know how it is done, Thanks!